# Use $EDITOR in the middle of a series of UNIX pipe commands

Tags: bash, unix, editor, pipe

I have a shell command that provides output that I would like to edit before piping it into another command.  This is not regular output that can easily be edited with `sed` and such.  My current approach is:

```
command-one > tmp
vim tmp
command-two < tmp
rm tmp
```

I would like to avoid the unnecessary creation of a temporary file and instead do something like `command-one | vim - | command-two` but that doesn't work because the actual onscreen output of vim gets piped into the command instead of being visible for me to edit.  This works in commands like `git commit` which wait for the temp file to be written before using the result.

Comment: `pipes` create tmp files, its just that you don't have to delete them when your pipeline completes. Make a script with your commands as listed in the first block and you'll be good to go. Good luck!

Comment: This is just one example.  I don't do the same scriptable action every time.  I just find myself often needing this pattern, so it isn't something that I could put in a script and be done with.

Comment: you'll get more respondents if you include a tag for the shell you're using (bash|ksh|csh|...). There might be some trick to get what you want, but I'll be surprized if 1. it exists, and 2 its not fragile. Good luck!.

Comment: `git commit` does not sit in the middle of a pipeline. Rather it takes input, runs `$EDITOR` to produce a temporary file, then does something with that temporary file.

Comment: Right, understood.  Just using it as an example of the workflow, if not the exact thing.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282366/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use some random editor (i.e. the value of `$EDITOR`), you'll need to use a temporary file. Most editors do not have the facility to accept an entire file on `stdin` and write it to `stdout` when the edit is finished.

See `mktemp` (or `tempfile` in the unlikely case that you don't have `mktemp`) for a safe way to create a temporary file.

Answer (score 6):

You could write a script with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh 
: ${EDITOR:=/usr/bin/vi} 
: ${TMPDIR:=/tmp} 

TMPFILE=${TMPDIR}/.edpipe$$ 

trap "trap '' 0 1 2 3 15; rm -f $TMPFILE; exit 0" 0 1 2 3 15 

cat >$TMPFILE 
$EDITOR ${1:+"$@"} $TMPFILE </dev/tty >/dev/tty 
cat $TMPFILE 
exit 0
```

Save the script as edpipe for example, and then call it in your pipeline like this

```
ls | edpipe | wc -l
```

Comment: This is one of the coolest answers I've ever seen on SO, feels like this should be a built in tool.

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Just suggesting to add `set -e` to the top of the script, such that it can be aborted. E.g. with `set -e`, I can exit vim with `:cq` to abort the rest of the pipeline.

Comment: `set -e` didn't abort the pipeline for me,  it just passed an empty file on.  This can be achieve by deleting the contents in vi eg `dGZZ`

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult as stated because, as you've pointed out, to fit into a pipeline like that the editor needs to display one thing to the user and output a different thing on stdout.

However, if the rest of the pipeline isn't too long/horrible, here's something you can do using vim:

```
$ vim <(first | part | of | pipeline)
```

This passes vim an argument which is a named pipe outputting the stdout of those commands. The effective result is that you get a buffer containing that output. Edit it, then, before exiting:

```
:w !rest | of | pipeline
```

which runs `rest | of | pipeline` in a shell and feeds the current buffer into its stdin. You'll see the output of the command within vim, and then you'll be able to `:q!` to discard the modified buffer and return to your shell.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called vipe (https://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) that is designed exactly for this purpose:

```
command | vipe | another-command
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp); command-one > $tmpfile && vim $tmpfile && command-two < $tmpfile && rm $tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up here wanting the same solution for #powershell rather than #bash

```
function Choose () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]
        $Text
    )
    begin {
        $file = New-TemporaryFile
        $Text
    }
    process 
    {
        foreach ($line in $Text){
            $line >> $file
        }
    }
    end{
        start-process nvim $file -wait
        Get-Content $file
        Remove-Item $file 
    }
}
```

and using it to edit the *git sparse checkout info*

```
function Git-Sparse-Checkout-Edit 
{
    git sparse-checkout list | Choose | git sparse-checkout set --stdin

}
```

The editor I'm using is [nvim](http://neovim.org) but should work with any editor. In case you wonder why *start-process* then I don't really know. The terminal would stall and become unresponsive if I didn't do it this way.